# The limit for Thomae's function

Tags: analysis

I want to ask a question about the limit of the Thomae's function.

This function looks like this:

$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x\in \mathbb{R} -\mathbb{Q}\\ \frac{1}{q}& x=\frac{p}{q}\ \ \mbox{ in reduced form }\end{cases} $

I know this function has a limit $ \displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=0 , \forall a \in \mathbb R $
However, I don't know how to prove it. I see some proof for the continuity of this function(continuous at irrational numbers, discontinuous in rational numbers), but I haven't seen any proof of the limit of this function.
Could someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: What proof(s) have you seen of this continuity property? The proof I'm familiar with basically proves $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$, and conclude continuity precisely on $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ as an immediate corollary.

Comment: Yeah, I see proofs on Wikipedia. It contains the proof for continuity, but it lacks the proof for the limit is zero for any real numbers

Comment: Presumably, [these ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)? If you look at the proof of continuity at the irrational numbers, you might notice that the only time that the irrationality assumption is used is to say the function evaluates to $0$ at the given irrational point. If you simply lose this assumption, and replace $f(x_0)$ with the proposed limit $0$, you get a perfectly sensible proof that the limit is $0$ regardless of whether $x_0 \in \Bbb{Q}$ or not. From this you can even conclude discontinuity on $\Bbb{Q}$, as $f(x_0) \neq 0$ for $x_0 \in \Bbb{Q}$ by definition.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to understand it

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I think I kind of understand something. When proving the limit is zero for x approaching any real number, I find that if $x \in \mathbb Q$ then we can find $ f(x)=\frac{1}{q} < \frac{1}{r} <\epsilon $ because of the wise choosing of $\delta$. If $ x \notin \mathbb Q $ Then $f(x)=0$ and $|f(x)-0|< \epsilon$ is always correct. As a result, the limit is zero

Comment: That's right! By choosing $\delta$ wisely, we eliminate all of the (only finitely many) "tall" function values (i.e. rationals $q$ such that $f(q) > \varepsilon$), which leaves only irrationals (with function value already at the limit of $0$), and the shorter function values at rational points.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much!